# C++ Indexing an array of ints using a short

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, int, short

Ok guys I asked a question 15 mins ago and closed it because when I tried a simple test in `main()`, it worked. However, it does not work in the actual code:

Background, I have an array of unsigned ints which I cannot access via an unsigned short indexer. If I declare an array on the stack it works, but it doesnt work for my array data member.

Here is the array declaration:

```
typedef unsigned int uint;

class OB{
public:
    OB();
    void x(unsigned short side_pos);

private:
    uint best_p[2]; 
};
```

and here's the code where I get the compiler error:

```
void OB::x(unsigned short side_pos){
    unsigned int best_price = best_p[side_pos];
}
```

If I do:

```
void OB::x(unsigned short side_pos){
    unsigned short something_else = 1;
    unsigned int best_price = best_p[something_else];
}
```

I also get the compiler error, which is:

```
OB.cpp: In member function ‘void OB::x(short unsigned int)’:
OB.cpp:62:56: error: invalid types ‘unsigned int[short unsigned int]’ for array subscript
     unsigned int best_price = best_p[side_pos];
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the *only* `best_p` and that there isn't, say, a local variable?

Comment: @chris put that as the answer (you were kinda right, in one of my compiler errors I did have a multiple declaration but for another I didnt and putting "this->my_array[]" fixed it).

Comment: Better: Use a different name. Shadowing can useful at times, but usually it just causes compilation errors.

Comment: @user997112 I already said you in the previous your post ALWAYS TRY TO COMPILE YOUR OWN CODE SNIPPET. Is it so difficult?!!! Your code snippet is compiled successfuly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on intuition and comment hints, you have a local variable `best_p` (an `unsigned int` by the looks of it) that's shadowing the member of your class. Thus, `best_p[side_pos]` will use the local variable, not the data member.

If you want the compiler to catch shadowing, the `-Wshadow` option should do it. The best thing to do when it does is rename something. Having a convention for data member names (`m_<name>` is a common one) can also help to prevent both accidental shadowing and thinking about what to rename something to.

Answer (score 1):

It compiles on my computer. Seems the way to get that error is to use a variable instead of an array. Check the names of your attributes.